# Error CS1061 on Request.Cookies["A"]["A1"].value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to set a cookie value to variable. But get Error CS1061.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web" %>
<script runat="server">

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Request.Cookies["A"]["A1"] != null)
    {
       var CookieA = Request.Cookies["A"]["A1"].Value;
    }
```

I get the fault on line with 'var CookieA'

I'm very new on this language and still learning lots. But this fault I have not been able to find an answer for.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out what I did wrong.

First declare CookieA as a string: `string CookieA;`

Then change this: `var CookieA = Request.Cookies["A"]["A1"].Value;`

Into this: `CookieA = Request.Cookies["A"]["A1"];`

Yay!